# Extraccion datos excel para crear lista Python

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, diccionarios

Tengo el siguiente archivo de excel:

```
connection A    auto
connection A    camioneta
connection A    puerta
connection B    camioneta
connection B    puerta
connection B    capo
```

y estoy buscando armar un dicc en python de esta forma:

```
Lista = {'connection A':["auto","camioneta","puerta"],
         'connection B':["camioneta","puerta","capo"]
         }
```

el archivo es .xlsx y necesito que por cada dato diferente que haya en la columna A del excel me cree un diccionario con todos los datos que correspondan a ese mismo campo. No se si se entendio lo que quiero hacer

Trabajo con python y no puedo usar otro software que no sea ese. (python 2.7)

Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué métodos has probado para leer la hoja de excel?

Comment: Hasta ahora ninguno. Nunca trabaje de esa forma

Comment: Martin cuando dices "no puedo usar otro software" supongo que si puedes instalar librerías python como pyxls, xlwings, pandas, etc. ¿No?

Comment: Exactactamente!

Comment: @FJSevilla Se te ocurre alguna forma de hacerlo??

Comment: @MartinBouhier hay multitud de librerias que permiten trabajar con archivos Excel, te dejo dos posibilidad muy simples usando Pandas o solamente openpyxl. No es algo complicado en cuanto a algoritmo, simplemente elige una biblioteca que te permita trabajar con xlsx de tu gusto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes multitud de bibliotecas para leer archivos Excel. Podemos usar [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/) junto a `collections.defaultdict`:

```
import collections
import openpyxl


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('dat.xlsx')
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Hoja1')

Lista = collections.defaultdict(list)
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    Lista[row[0].value].append(row[1].value)
```

Un objeto `itertools.defaultdict` se puede usar exactamente igual que un diccionario normal.

---

Otra opción es usar Pandas y aprovecharse del método [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html). Si no vas a operar con los datos y solo quieres obtener el diccionario esta opción es posiblemente demasido para algo tan simple, no obstante.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("datos.xlsx", header = None).pivot(columns = 0,  values = 1)
Lista = {col: df[col].dropna().tolist() for col in df.columns}
```

Para un archivo como el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Obtenemos:

```
>>> Lista
{'connection A': ['auto', 'camioneta', 'puerta'],
 'connection B': ['camioneta', 'puerta', 'capo']}
```

---

> **Nota:** Tanto `pandas` como `openpyxl` son bibliotecas python externas que han de ser instaladas, via `pip` por ejemplo.

**Edición:**

Para almacenar la variable en un fichero existen múltiples formas. Una muy simple es serializar el objeto usando cPickle/Pickle:

```
import collections
import pickle
import openpyxl


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('dat.xlsx')
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Hoja1')

Lista = collections.defaultdict(list)
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    Lista[row[0].value].append(row[1].value)

# Ahora serializamos el objeto Lista.
# El archivo lo vamos a llamar `Lista.dat`:

with open("Lista.dat", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(Lista, f)
```

Ahora podemos desde cualquier módulo deserializar el objeto:

```
import pickle

with open("Lista.dat", "rb") as f:
    Lista = pickle.load(f)

print(Lista)
```

Comment: Funciona pero me agrega una u adelante de todos los valores:
`{u'connection A': [u'auto', u'camioneta',u 'puerta'],
 u'connection B': [u'camioneta', u'puerta', u'capo']}`

Comment: `u"cadena"` solo indica que es una cadena con codificación unicode.

Comment: Gracias. Por otro lado te pregunto, yo utilizo un dicc con listas dentro como en el ejemplo y lo tengo todo dentro de un .py. Queria saber como puedo guardar esa Lista en un .py. Por el momento puedo reproducirla con print pero necesito que la guarde como un .py. Gracias

Comment: @MartinBouhier no entiendo muy bién lo que pretendes, si quieres almacenar tu variable Lista para usarla en otro momento sin tener que leer el Excel lo normal es almacenarlo en un archivo binario o mejor serializar el objeto con [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) y deserializarlo cuando lo necesites. Modificar el código de un módulo .py mediante código aunque posible no es buena idea por seguridad, legibilidad y estabilidad del programa.

Comment: Lo que quiero es almacenar la variable Lista en un .py o como dices que no es recomendable, como podria hacer? Necesito que se almacene en algun tipo de file para ejecutarlo con otro codigo que tengo de python! Lo quiero hacer asi porque en un file tengo el codigo de mi programa y en el otro la lista de datos

Comment: @MartinBouhier he editado la respuesta, al final te dejo un ejemplo usando pickle (es parte de la biblioteca estándar, no tienes que instalar nada). Lo que hacemos es una vez leido y obtenido Lista desde esl xlsx lo serializamos a un archivo en disco. Este archivo puede ser deserializado cuando quieres y desde cualquier módulo python. Puedes serializar varios objetos en un mismo archivo si lo deseas.

Comment: Perfecto gracias, Volviendo a lo anterior y perdon pero recien me doy cuenta de esto... en la columna A del excel yo trabajo con numeros en realidad no con nombres y cuando ejecuto el codigo si tengo numeros me salen asi: 9864 y cuando tengo nombres asi: u'connectionA'. Necesito que los numeros salgan asi: u,'9864'

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67965/discussion-between-fjsevilla-and-martin-bouhier).

Answer (score 2):

Hola yo uso una librería `xlrd`   sirve para leer

```
import xlrd

wb2 = xlrd.open_workbook(ruta)
#ruta es obviamente algo como "archivo.xls"
sheet = wb2.sheet_by_index(0)
```

asumiendo que tu archivo excel tiene solo una hoja de datos y es la primera o sea la `0`

```
dir_cantidad = len(sheet.col_values(0)) - 1
#asumiendo que tus datos comienzan en la `columna A = 0`
# dir cantidad contiene todos las celdas desde la fila 1 hasta que encuentre datos

Lista = {}

for i in range(0,dir_cantidad):
    # i tomara el valor de cada fila así,   1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
    connection = sheet.cell(i, 0).value
    #asumiendo que tu primer dato esta en 0, 0 es decir, Columna A Fila 1

    if connection in Lista:
        conn = Lista.get(connection)
        conn.append(sheet.cell(i, 1).value)
        #asumiendo que tu siguiente dato esta en columna B = 1
        Lista[connection] = conn
    else:
        Lista[connection] = [sheet.cell(i, 1).value]
```

En realidad lo único que hace es leer tu hoja de datos, y poner los datos en un nuevo diccionario, si la llave ya existe agrega esta al valor actual.

Aunque vale precisar que el resultado es un Diccionario `{}` no una lista `[]`, el valor que contiene la llave en este caso si es una lista

Espero te sirva. Saludos